# Will Sheets V3 APIs be operational after it's retirement

Tags: google-sheets-api

Sheets V3 APIs are said to be retiring by March 2020, however I would like to understand if they would still be operational even after it's retirement?
Is it mandatory to migrate all my existing Apps from V3 to V4? Going on, is it so that I can use V4 instead of V3, and let existing apps work on V3, as they are currently functioning, or will the retirement affect/stop the existing live app's working because of V3 deprecation?

Would be great if anyone can provide any help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On March 3, 2020, v3 is **shutting down**. The API endpoints won't be available and you should migrate your projects to v4 before that date. Google offers a [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration) for that.

#### Reference:

- [Sheets API v3 (Legacy)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/worksheets)
- [Migrate to v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration?_ga=2.55269995.-1197071020.1580459294)

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, what is the error code/message which we would get after the shut down date?

Comment: @NikitaDhuse Since the endpoints wouldn't be available, the request wouldn't find it, so you would get a 404 error or similar.